How to configure Embedded Tomcat such that the classloader will find classes in CATALINA_HOME/lib
I have an issue with embedded Tomcat and classloaders.
I have a java servlet application that runs in an embedded Tomcat(9.0.70) instance. When the application is packaged into a single war file – the application loads and performs as expected (classes are fond in WEB-INF/lib.
Due to some system constraints it is necessary to deliver the application code separate from its dependencies.
I modified the application pom to copy the dependencies to ${project.build.directory}/lib/
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>                         <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib/</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

and to exclude the jar files from the war file
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
             <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
 </plugin> 

this builds the project as expected – 1 war file and one lib directory.
The class that creates the embedded Tomcat environment includes (much abbreviated):
System.setProperty("catalina.home", catHome) ;
tomcat.start();
server = tomcat.getServer();
File    base    = server.getCatalinaBase();
File    home    = server.getCatalinaHome();
log.info("starting on port:" + sslPort + 
             " with home:" + home.getAbsolutePath() + 
            " base:" + base.getAbsolutePath());

The logging confirms that CATALINA_HOME is se to the required dir.
On execution receive ClassNotFoundException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet                        
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1412)              
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)              
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)                                                     
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:396)                                          
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:357)                                                  
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:154)                                  
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2472)      
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:875)               
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1376)              
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)              
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:534)               
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:515)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:149)             
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1067)                          
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1007)                                 
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4948)                        
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5256)                        
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)                                     
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)                          
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383)                          
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)                                                 
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)              
 at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)                    
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)                             
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)                               
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)                                     
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)                          
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383)                          
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)                                                 
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)              
 at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)                    
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)                             
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)  
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)            
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:430)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)            
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)  
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)            
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) 

my understanding from https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html is that the Tomcat common loader will search for jars in CATALINA_HOME/lib.  My $CATALINA_HOME/lib contains gwt-user-2.10.0.jar which contains RemoteServiceServlet.class.
What do I need to do to resolve from CATALINA_HOME/lib
do i need my own classloader - from the Tomcat doc the common loader should be sufficient (I think)

When using embedded Tomcat the standard Tomcat classloader structure does not apply. You have to include the required jar files on the classpath definition
